# what is the role and meaning of "=>" operator (it's called maps to) in apex enterprise pattern application class ? Please explain

Tags: apex, fflib

```
@namespaceAccessible
public static final fflib_Application.ServiceFactory service = new fflib_Application.ServiceFactory(new Map<Type, Type>
{
     IHospitalService.class => HospitalServiceImpl.class
     //what is "=>" ??
     //what is the role and meaning of "=>"
}
)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's... just another operator that Apex provides?

There's no special meaning here, no hidden message to decipher. It's used when you're initializing a `Map`.

Break down the statement into parts, and this should become very clear.

- `public static final fflib_Application.ServiceFactory service` = declaring a static variable
- `= new fflib_Application.ServiceFactory(...)` = creating a new object instance to put into that variable by calling the constructor
- `new Map<Type, Type>{ IHospitalService.class => HospitalServiceImpl.class }` = creating a new Map, using `IHospitalService.class` as a key, and `HospitalServiceImpl.class` as the associated value. This Map is an argument provided to the `fflib_Application.ServiceFactory()` constructor

Answer (score 0):

The `=>` operator was likely borrowed from some languages that used this operator in a similar fashion. The intent is to look like an arrow (→), such that `'key' → 'value'`. You'll find this in Ruby, for example: `{ 'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2' }`. It has no special significance except to say that other languages have employed arrows to demonstrate assignment or relationship. For example, some old languages would write something like `x ← 5` to indicate 5 being assigned to x.

I can't really speculate on why they wanted the arrow notation. It could be because of historical precedence, or perhaps they needed an operator that the parser wouldn't confuse for something else (e.g. `:` was already in use), or perhaps some combination of the two. Whatever the reason, `=>` continues to be the way that you construct map with initial key-value pairs. You should use this operator when possible, as it is faster to initialize a Map this way than to add the values one at a time.